# How to get the latest value?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, datagrip

I am trying to write a query and I want to get only the max(date), and I have to group by the rest of info such as job_ID, invoice, total_paid, and payment_method.

I can't group by the payment method because logically its not correct and also because the payment methods are different... and, I cannot use listagg here.

Any idea how can I accomplish my goal?
I almost reached the end but the payment method cause some errors in the code...

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Provide complete CREATE TABLE, some sample data as INSERT INTO (both scripts as code-formatted text) and show desired output for this data with detailed explanations. Also specify precise DBserver version.

Comment: Don't include payment method in your query. Then you don't need to group by it. If you need info what payment method was on that specific line, you can query it with another SQL query.

Comment: You tagged MySQL as well as Snowflake, but they are not the same. Your question is missing lots of information for others to effectively help to resolve your issue. Please update your question with more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the row with the max `date` for any `id` with a `qualify row_number() over()`:

```sql
with data as (
    select $1 id, $2 date, $3 value
    from values (1, 1, 'a')
        , (1, 2, 'b')
        , (1, 3, 'c')
        , (2, 1, 'e')
        , (2, 2, 'f')
        , (2, 3, 'g')
)

select *
from data
qualify row_number() over(partition by id order by date desc) = 1
;
```

[image]

If this is not what you want — you will need to improve the question by detailing sample input data and desired results.